# How can I hookup my laptop to a non HD TV?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gateway

My Computer is a Gateway ID59C I just bought it about 4 months ago. How can I hook it up to the TV so that I can watch Movies and stuff off my computer? and getting a brand new HD TV really isn't a answer.

Comment: This basically comes down to what your computer can output, and what connections you have available on your T.V. If you could add some additional information on the make/model of your T.V. as well, someone might be able to tell you the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which connections are available on your TV. Most TVs in recent years have a VGA connector, and you'd connect to it much like you connect to a monitor (although you'd need to add a 3.5" audio connector as well if you'd like to use your TV speakers).

If your TV only supports composite, then @MHrappstead answer is what you're looking for. Similarly, you can convert VGA to S-Video, if that's what your TV supports.

Finally, let us not forget DLNA solutions. If you have an Xbox 360, a PS3 or a DLNA-supporting media box, you can just stream your video to the TV over your network.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a [VGA to Composite Converter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158142&cm_re=vga_composite-_-15-158-142-_-Product) and a [Y Splitter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16882339049&cm_re=y_splitter_cable-_-82-339-049-_-Product). Or you could get a [VGA to Component Converter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707073&cm_re=vga_component-_-17-707-073-_-Product) but this would depend on what your TV supports. Also make sure you do your own research on which converter or y splitter your going to buy as the hyperlinks I've provided are just there to give you an idea of what products you should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your TV has a PC input just use a standard VGA monitor cable to connect the computer to the TV with RCA audio cables. Or You can use cables to convert your computer output (HDMI or VGA) to the type of input for you TV (standard audio/video[RCA], Component, PC, s-video, etc).

Just conduct a web search for "output to input". For example searching for "HDMI to component" returns this cable from Amazon as one of it's results.    [http://www.amazon.com/Component-Video-Stereo-Audio-Cable/dp/B001IUQB2W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IUQB2W)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specs](http://support.gateway.com/s/notebook/2010/gateway/id/id59C/ID59Csp2.shtml) I found from the computer model you posted, you should have a VGA output on your computer. (You also have an HDMI port, but you specifically said that you don't want to buy and HD T.V., so I guess you already thought about that). If your T.V. has a corresponding input (I'm not sure what kind of T.V. you have available), it should be as easy as purchasing a VGA cable and hooking it up.

[image]